# References to MappedBySuperclass-classes

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following problem. I have an abstract class called Vehicle, this class is annotated with MappedBySuperclass. Then I have lots of classes extending that abstract class, such as Car, Boat, Bicycle, Motorcycle etc etc etc.
I also have a class called Person. A person owns a set of vehicles. I would like the relation to look like this

```
@Entity
class Person {
   @OneToMany
   List<Vehicle> vehicles;

   ...
}
```

The problem is that Vehicle is an abstract class and not an entity-class directly. Is there any way in JPA I can use this kind of reference without referring directly to the entity-class?

Answer (score 1):

It should work like this. Here is [blog](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/why_sometimes_the_entitymanager_in?bcsi_scan_0057666496C92DC4=0) entry where the author did something similar and said, it worked very well. Hope it helps!